# BroadcastReceiver and orientation change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

As far as i know `onReceive()` always get called on the UI thread (unless it's explicitly defined otherwise),

Let's say i'm doing some work on a background `Thread` and sending a broadcast with the result when finished.

What happens if i have a registered receiver for that broadcast in an `Activity` and an orientation change is in progress when the broadcast is getting sent?

Is it guaranteed that i will receive the broadcast when the orientation change is finished?

I guess this depends on which lifecycle method my receiver got registered in.

In other words: When will `onReceive()` run after an orientation change (if the broadcast is coming from a background thread)?